# scene7 url alignment attribute

Tags: adobe, scene7

I have to integrate the scene7 url in the imageview. I am passing the width(wid) and height(hei) attribute to scene7 url to draw the image in the imageview. However, if the image content size in the scene 7 url is less than desired size, it always draw image in center. Is there any attribute which will align the image to the left of the container box in scene7?

Note- Tried `align` attribute of scene7 url, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

`align` should work, something like `https://<domain>/is/image/<image_name>.jpg?$<named_preset>$&align=-1,0` and then can add `fit=constrain,0` in order to avoid white-space if needed.

[Read more](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/dynamic-media-developer-resources/image-serving-api/image-serving-api/http-protocol-reference/command-reference/r-fit.html)